# Floating point precision affected when converting DataFrame to list

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, floating-point-precision

So I'm trying to convert a float DataFrame to a list (of list) by using `row.values.tolist()` (`row` was read from a CSV file). It does the job pretty okay though for a few values the precision is being affected, so, for instance, instead of `32.337` it's outputting `32.336999999999996.`

Since `tolist()` yields a *list of list* and I need to work with *lists*, I decided to switch to `list(row.values.flatten())`, but it introduces precision issues for almost **any** value in the list, which just makes it worst.

I found a [discussion on Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2069) about this issue, from almost 3 years ago, but I can't find anything else up to date and I have no idea how to overcome this.

I tried using `pd.set_option('display.precision',4)` since for most values I need a maximum of four significant digits, but this isn't working either (assuming I'm using it right).

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: how does the visual representation affect your application?

Answer (score 2):

The "loss of precision" you're seeing is due to the fact that binary floating-point can't precisely represent decimal fractions, so there's some rounding error. If you really want to pass decimal values through unchanged, you'd get better results using an actual decimal representation...

Unfortunately, NumPy doesn't seem to provide any decimal datatypes for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough, you might still have a problem with precision depending on the base values.
 You can still use `round` to specify the amount of decimal you wish to have.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(.2132481, .399452), (.012311, .13267), (.613216, .01233), (.213211, .181235)])
df.values.round(3).tolist()

>> [[0.213, 0.399], [0.012, 0.133], [0.613, 0.012], [0.213, 0.181]]
```

The `3` in `.round(3)` goes for three decimals.

Answer (score 0):

As Padraic alluded, you are not modifying the correct option with `display.precision`.  Instead, try:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```